# Firebase Firestore data saving not working IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code and why firebase isn't saving the data but I can't figure out why.

Code in question:

```
func save() {

    let userDict: [String: Any] = ["uid" : uid!, "username" : username!, "fullName" : fullName!, "email" : email!, "age" : age!, "score" : 0]

    // Savving to Firestore database
    db.collection("users").document(uid!).setData(userDict) { (error:Error?) in

        if let error = error {

            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {

            print("Document was created")

        }

    }

    // Storing the profile image
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("\(uid!).png")

    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage!) {

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadeta, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print(error!)
                return
            }



        })

    }

}
```

The image is being stored in the Firebase storage but the user data isn't being stored in the cloud firestore. So this means that it's running through my code but not working properly. If anyone can give any insight to why this is happening, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe changing 
child("(uid!).png")
to name of the file without .png
because your creating a file that you want to upload to 
so naming a file with uid which will be a number and with .png it wont a file at all so you need is this child("(uid!)/yourImage.png")

Comment: The question is about the user record not being saved.